# Keyboard issues in iphone 6 and 6 plus during orientation changes

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have an app which has one viewcontroller which works for both landscape as well portrait mode, Now when app goes to  the landscape mode and coming back to portrait, the keyboard doesn't appear at all until app quits.

The issues is not related to iOS 8.0 for sure, because it works well in iPhone 5S with iOS 8.0 but it doesn't work for iPhone 6 and 6+. Also checked the keyboard frame and its shows correctly, but the keyboard doesn't show up. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Or is there a way i can force the keyboard to show up.

Comment: Are you using simulator? If yes, iOS_Simulator->Hardware->Keyboard then uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard" will display the keyboard inside simulator. Else if keyboard appears not as expected then Daniel McCarthy's solution will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding Launch Images for both the iPhone 6 and 6+? Without specific Launch Images for the 2 new device resolutions, the app will basically pretend that the width is still 320px and just stretch everything out to fit the bigger screen. I have seen this cause many strange problems with the keyboard on iPhone 6 and 6+ devices, and it sounds like this may be the underlying issue here as well. Here are the Launch Image resolutions you need for both devices:

For iPhone 6:
750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait ---
1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

For iPhone 6 Plus:
1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait ---
2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yes the launch screen was missing and it created the issue.